# How to make TextBox continually update with user's input?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, validation

I have a `TextBox` in my form, the user should enter some string there.

After each 2 characters, it should automatically add a `"|"` in there. But I don't know how to do that. Here's my code:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string input = textBox1.Text; int count = 0;
    foreach (char c in input)
    {
        count++;
        if (count == 2)
        {
            input += '|';
            count = 0;
            textBox1.Text = input;
        }
    }
}
```

- The user should only enter the characters in hexadecimals (meaning 0-9, a-f).

I've tried the `e.Keychar` on the `Keypress` event, but it doesn't work, if the user use `Copy-Paste` and `Ctrl-C`, `Ctrl-V`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't handle the `TextChanged` event if you don't really have to, but you should rely on the `MaskedTextBox`, which is built for this exact purpose.

You can find a good walk-through [here on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/kkx4h3az(v=vs.100).aspx).

Basically you should set the `Mask` property. You can even use [sort of regular expressions as a mask](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms234064.aspx) to make sure only the values you allow are typed in.

---

The 'how-to':

Create a `MaskedTextBox` control and set the mask to `&&\|&&\|&&\|&&\|&&` ('&' means any ASCII character, repeat `\|&&` as much as you need). Then create a `TextChanged` event and set the event handler to this:

```
void maskedTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    string input = this.maskedTextBox1.Text;

    StringBuilder outputBuilder = new StringBuilder(input.Length);
    char[] allowedCharacters = new char[] { '|', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' };

    foreach (char c in input)
    {
        if (allowedCharacters.Contains(c))
        {
            outputBuilder.Append(c);
        }
    }

    string output = outputBuilder.ToString();
    if (!input.Equals(output))
    {
        this.maskedTextBox1.Text = output;
    }
}
```

Comment: But the first problem is not solved, and it's more important :(

Comment: What first problem? Both problems (the masking and allowing only hexadecimals) are solvable with this control. No need for you to code the event handler.

Comment: The one with"After each 2 characters, it should automatically add a "|" in there. But I don't know how to do that".

Comment: You can achieve that with this control too. Did you read the linked walk-throughs?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? I'm new in C# :(

Comment: Thank you very much. But somehow i can't add numbers :(

Answer (score 0):

**1st problem algorithmic solution**

Check if the index is even and > 0 and shift the characters to the left to make space for the '|' character.

```
for (int i=0; i<input.length; i++)
{
    var c = input[i];
    
    if (i % 2 == 0 && i>0)
    {
        
        for(int j=input.length-1; j>=i; j++) input[j+1] = input[j];
        input[i] = '|';
        textBox1.Text = input;
    }
}
```

Make sure you have enough space in input (if it's a primitive type collection)

Answer (score 0):

One issue with your current code is that the text changed event fires even when you programmatically update the textBox. One way to avoid that is to detect when the text change is caused by you. In the sample below, I've done this by checking if "|" is within 2 characters from the end of the string.

Use a StringBuilder to incrementally build up a string to avoid generating multiple String objects.

The mod operation could be replaced with a mask that extracted the least significant bit if you really wanted to eke out that bit of optimization.

```
  private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     string input = textBox1.Text;
     // did I cause this event to fire? if not, parse the input
     if (input.LastIndexOf("|") < input.Length - 2)
     {
        input = input.Replace("|", "");
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
           stringBuilder.Append(input[i]);
           if (i % 2 == 1)
           {
              stringBuilder.Append("|");
           }
        }
        textBox1.Text = stringBuilder.ToString();
        textBox1.Select(textBox1.Text.Length, 0);
     }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Avoid `CTRL` key press.

```
if (e.Control == true)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Cut/Copy and Paste Options are disabled");
}
```

Comment: This does not work for right-click Paste by the way.

Comment: Why would such a constraint be allowed or necessary?